# Django Admin Error. "Could not import my_app.views.admin_user"

Tags: python, django

In my urls, I have:

`from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()`

`url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),`

Everything was working OK last night. Today I tried to login to my Django admin just to get this error message.

```
ViewDoesNotExist at /admin/
Could not import my_app.views.admin_user. View does not exist in module my_app.views.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
Django Version: 1.7.1
Exception Type: ViewDoesNotExist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The django error is not very descriptive, importing manually may help reveal the issue.

`python ./manage.py shell` and try importing `my_app.views.admin_user` manually:

```
from my_app.views import admin_user
```

Side Note: You shouldn't need to call autodiscover (if django >= 1.7). As long as `'django.contrib.admin'` is in your `INSTALLED_APPS` it will handle that for you automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the response. In shell, all I get is `ImportError: cannot import name admin_user`

Comment: Can you ensure both `'my_app'` and `'django.contrib.admin'` are listed under `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`?

Comment: yes, they are both installed. I'm using a custom user model, and last night was doing some modifications in my admin.py file but everything worked until I suspended the computer. This morning ... nothing :(

Comment: I found the issue, I added some urls to my urls.py that are clashing with the admin, didnt realize it would be an issue as they are `url(r'^myaccount/admin/users/$', ...`. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Not sure what I was thinking, I added two new urls to my urls.py that I was planning to work on and never created the views for those urls and that triggered the error and got me all confused :)